# How can I revert all local changes excluding what is in a change set using SmartSVN

Tags: svn, smartsvn

Using SmartSVN, I would like to revert all local changes excluding files within a change set using a single command.

Using `Revert Recursively` from the root folder reverts files within the change set.

Is it possible to revert all files and folders excluding what is in the change set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a patch file of the files that you need to retain, then doing a recursive revert from the root folder and then finally applying the patch file to the working copy to restore the files you wanted to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle **View|Files Assigned to Change Sets** to hide them from the **Files** view, then select all remaining files and invoke **Revert**.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include folders in my original description. This approach works great if its just files but not so much with folders. It also wouldn't get rid of present files that don't exist in the repo.